# Eclipse not saving my modifications in the current project

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, editor

I change a println in my code but after Refresh -> Build Project -> Run as Server the result is still the old output.

I'm sure it's about Eclipse so what can I do to make it work ?
Also, do you know another editor like Eclipse which have an embedded tomcat server and more or less the same functionnalities ? (more stable of course)

[image]

Comment: which framework are you using?

Comment: did you stopped the server and run again? 
after stopping server try go to this option from top menu bar of your eclipse "project -> clean" and rerun your application

Comment: I use Struts 2, and I already did project -> clean but with same result.. I will try to copy paste the project folder elsewhere and see what happens but I'm not confident

Comment: Debug on Server and set some breakpoints instead. See if it's actually executing the changed line.